# Non-blocking read of /dev/input/mice in java

Tags: linux, file-io, mouse, real-time

I am trying to poll a mouse and update its position in Java using "/dev/input/mice". However right now I cannot figure out a way to determine if there is new data. How do I read an input file in a non-blocking way?

```
public class Mouse {

    String MOUSE_STREAM = "/dev/input/mice";
    BufferedInputStream bis;

    private Mouse(){
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File (MOUSE_STREAM)));
    }

    public Vect getDelta() {
        int sumX = 0;
        int sumY = 0;
        // This is what I want, but available always returns 0;
        // while (bis.available() > 3) {

            // Otherwise, If I don't check then .read() will block until the next event
            int buttons = bis.read();
            int x = bis.read();
            int y = bis.read();
            sumX += x;
            sumY += y;
        }
        return new Vect(sumX, sumY);
    }
}
```

PS I need to be using a very low level interface because I'm operating in a Real-Time version of linux without much support for higher level libraries.